# simple x86-64 assembly arithmetic

Tags: assembly

I am trying to write assembly language code for the formula in the comment. I am having trouble because the pointers to the arrays are 64 bit registers, and I am supposed to store the final result in a 32 bit register, so I am obviously missing some fundamental understanding of how registers work. I included my attempted solution, but I get errors when I try to use a movl or subl where one argument is a 64 bit register and the other is 32 bits. I'm also not certain if my reasoning is even correct. Any help would be appreciated.

```
#    WRITEME: At this point, %r12 and %rbx are each pointers to two arrays
#   of 3 ints apiece, a0 and a1.  Your job is to write assembly language code
#   in the space below that evaluates the following expression, putting the
#   result in register %esi (the 32 bit form of register %rsi):
#   
#    (a1[0]-a0[0]) * (a1[0]-a0[0]) + 
#    (a1[1]-a0[1]) * (a1[1]-a0[1]) + 
#    (a1[2]-a0[2]) * (a1[2]-a0[2])
#   
#    
#   It is possible to do this using 11 instructions. You need to use extra
#   registers, of course. Since  you are not calling any functions, you have a
#   lot of choices. %r12 and %rbx are already occupied, but you could use
#   %r13d through %r15d (32 bit forms of %r13 through r15) safely, and also
#   %eax, %ecx, %edx and of course %esi, since that is where the result will
#   be stored.

###########

# Your code here
movl $0, %esi
movl %rbx, %eax #errors here
subl %r12, %eax #and here
imull %eax, %eax
movl 4(%rbx), %ecx
subl 4(%r12), %ecx
imull %ecx, %ecx
movl 8(%rbx), %edx
subl 8(%r12), %edx
imull %edx, %edx
movl %eax, %esi
addl %ecx, %esi
addl %edx, %esi
```

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing the contents of the 64 bit registers with the contents pointed at by the address in those registers.  If I understand your issue correctly, if you use the 64 bit registers to get at the data (which may very well be only 32 bit) and sum that, you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`movl %rbx, %eax` means: 'copy the contents of rbx into eax', however since rbx is a 64-bit register, while eax is a 32-bit register this will fail. I think what you mean to do is 'copy the contents of memory pointed to by rbx into eax': `movl rbx %eax`